# Removing HTML Tags from Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have the a column in my table which stores a paragraph like below :

`<p><img src="https://mywebsite.com/medias/NH2xcoUOfANfFb6l4xNgOFch3dc4TvoX2XBnI6to.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="33"></p><p><span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Mali, cursive; font-weight: 500;">My beautiful text is here. Show me without tags, please.</span>&nbsp;</p>`

I want to remove all the html tags and, if possible, replace an HTML image to `(Image)`text.

So my expected output will be like below :

`(Image) My beautiful text is here. Show me without tags, please.`

OR just

`My beautiful text is here. Show me without tags, please.`

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below naive approach

```
select html, 
  regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(
      regexp_replace(html, 
        r'<img [^<>]*>',   r'(Image) '), 
        r'(&)([^&;]*)(;)', r'<\2>'
      ),r'\<[^<>]*\>',    ''
    ) as text
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

As you can see first step is to replace Image Tag with `(Image)`  text, second step is to address HTML encoding by enclosing them into <...> - for example `&nbsp;` becomes `<&nbsp;>`  and finally remove everything between and including `<` and `>`

Note: above is simplistic approach  - might not work for more complex htmls